# Unable to locate package openAL

Tags: installation, apt

After this command

```
sudo apt-get install openal
```

I got this message:

```
E: Unable to locate package openal
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, you can always search packages using apt-cache:

```
apt-cache search openal
```

Then you will find out, that you need to install `libopenal` (`libopenal1` in Ubuntu 12.04)

Answer (score 12):

Use the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libalut-dev
```

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 16 where `openal` doesn't exist